# Why LiveBroadcasts: list does not support multiple filters?

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

Currently, I am trying to fetch the upcoming live and active live from LiveBroadcasts: list YouTube Streaming API on logged in account.

And I would like to filter the video with multiple types like: `type=active,upcoming`.

How can I fetch the list of upcoming and active live on logged in account with LiveBroadcasts: list API?

I tried to fetch with `mine=true&type=active` but seems like it does not support multiple filters therefore it occurs 400 Incompatible parameters error.

also, `type=active,upcoming` does not work neither.

Thank you.